# Show that $(A\textbf{v})\cdot\textbf{w}=\textbf{v}\cdot(A^T\textbf{w})$

Tags: matrices

Show that for every $A\in\mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$,  $\textbf{v}\in\mathbb{R}^n$, $\textbf{w}\in\mathbb{R}^m$,

$$\left(A\textbf{v}\right)\cdot\textbf{w}=\textbf{v}\cdot\left(A^T\textbf{w}\right).$$

I know that I'm supposed to be using the summation convention $\textbf{v}=v_i\textbf{e}_i=\sum_{i=1}^{3}v_i\textbf{e}_i$ as well as the Levi-Civita symbol $\epsilon_{ijk}$ and the Kronecker delta $\delta_{ij}$.

Thanks!

PS: I reckon I could get the next part of the question if I could do the first part, but if you wanted to know, it's: Hence prove that if the matrix $Q\in\mathbb{R^{n\times n}}$ is orthogonal, that is if $Q^T=Q^{-1}$, then
$$(Q\textbf{v})\cdot(Q\textbf{w})=\textbf{v}\cdot\textbf{w}$$ and $$\vert Q\textbf{v}\vert=\vert\textbf{v}\vert.$$

Comment: Why don't you just multiply out the formulae $\langle Av, w \rangle$, $\langle v, A^T w \rangle$ and see if they are the same? You can use the first result along with the fact that $Q^T Q = I$ to answer the second part.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$\begin{eqnarray*}
\left(A\textbf{v}\right)\cdot\textbf{w}
&=& (A{\bf v})_i w_i \\
&=& (A_{ij}v_j) w_i \\
&=& v_j (A_{ij} w_i) \\
&=& v_j ((A^T)_{ji}w_i) \\
&=& v_j (A^T{\bf w})_j \\
&=&\textbf{v}\cdot\left(A^T\textbf{w}\right)
\end{eqnarray*}$$

Comment: Ah great! Thanks oen.

Comment: @user72786: Glad to help. Follow copper.hat's advice for the next part.

Comment: Would this be the next part then?

$$\left(Q\mathbf{v}\right)\cdot\left(Q\mathbf{w})\right) =\left(Q\mathbf{v}\right)_i\left(Q\mathbf{w}\right)_i$$
$$=\left(Q_{ij}v_j\right)\left(Q_{ij}w_j\right)$$
$$=Q_{ij}Q_{ij}\left(v_jw_j\right)$$
$$=Q_{ij}\left(Q^{T}\right)_{ji}\left(v_jw_j\right)$$
$$=QQ^{-1}\left(v_jw_j\right)$$
$$=\mathbf{v}\cdot\mathbf{w}.$$

Comment: @user72786: We can now avoid components by using the above result: $(Q{\bf v})\cdot(Q{\bf w}) = {\bf v}\cdot(Q^TQ{\bf w}) = \ldots$.

Comment: Oh great! :) Thanks again!

Comment: @user72786: You're welcome. Here's how it looks in components - we need to be careful to use different dummy variables for different sums, 
$$\begin{eqnarray*}
\left(Q\textbf{v}\right)\cdot (Q \textbf{w})
&=& (Q{\bf v})_i (Q{\bf w})_i \\
&=& (Q_{ij}v_j) (Q_{ik}w_k) \\
&=& Q_{ij}Q_{ik} v_j w_k \\
&=& (Q^T)_{ji}Q_{ik} v_j w_k \\
&=& (Q^T Q)_{jk} v_j w_k \\
&=& I_{jk} v_j w_k \\
&=& \delta_{jk}v_j w_k \\
&=& v_j w_j \\
&=&\textbf{v}\cdot\textbf{w}.
\end{eqnarray*}$$

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align*}
\langle Av, w \rangle &= (Av)^T w \\
&= v^T A^T w \\
&= \langle v, A^T w \rangle.
\end{align*}